# Why can't you pick the elementalist archetype with the Elemental Sorcerer?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, archetype

I'm using Pathbuilder 2 to create a character and came across something that I don't understand how it is working.

Sorcerer's Bloodline feature reads:

> Choose a bloodline that gives you your spellcasting talent.  This
> choice determines the type of spells you cast and **the spell list**
> you choose them from [...]

The Elemental Bloodline has the Primal spell list.

The elementalist archetype has only one prerequisite:

> Prerequisites: You must have a spellcasting class feature that chooses
> spells from the arcane or **primal spell list**.

However, from pathbuilder I am unable to select the archetype, it's considered invalid. Can someone help me clarify why is that and what options do I have to pick it up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You're likely selecting it wrong.

In [Elementalist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=98), note that the Elemental Magic *class feature* (which is what has the prerequisite of "You must have a spellcasting class feature that chooses spells from the arcane or primal spell list.") is separate from the [Elementalist Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2986) feat (which has a prerequisite of the *Elemental Magic* class feature). This is because you have to choose to be an elementalist at level 1 (which also forces your level 2 class feat to be the dedication).

My guess is that you're trying to take the dedication feat at level 2, instead of looking for the class archetype. For Pathbuilder, in order to take a class archetype, you select it in place of a class (which is wrong, but that's how the app works). When you go to select a class, you'll see 4 options at the top: All Classes, Core, Expanded, and Class Archetypes.

[image: All Classes Core Expanded Class Archetypes]

Class archetypes *do not* show up in "All Classes", instead you need to select "Class Archetypes", and inside there will be an option for "Sorcerer (Elemental Magic)".

Something to note here, is that for some reason Pathbuilder erroneously does not force you to select the dedication feat at level 2, so you need to select that on your own.